# UVa's 3n+1 - why does my code exceed time limit?

Tags: java

The question is explained as below.

Consider the following algorithm:

```
    1.       input n
    2.       if n = 1 then STOP
    3.               if n is odd then  n = 3n+1 
    4.               else  n=n/2 
    5.       GOTO 2
```

Given the input `22`, the following sequence of numbers will be printed :

```
  22 11 34 17 52 26 13 40 20 10 5 16 8 4 2 1
```

It is conjectured that the algorithm above will terminate (when a 1 is printed) for any integral input value. Despite the simplicity of the algorithm, it is unknown whether this conjecture is true. It has been verified, however, for all integers `n` such that `0 < n < 1,000,000` (and, in fact, for many more numbers than this.)
Given an input `n`, it is possible to determine the number of numbers printed (including the 1). For a given n this is called the cycle-length of n. In the example above, the cycle length of `22` is `16`.
For any two numbers `i` and `j` you are to determine the maximum cycle length over all numbers between `i` and `j`.

```
Sample Input: 1 10
Sample Output: 1 10 20
```

Here is my solution.

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        new N1().run();
    }
    public static String readLine(int maxLength) {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[maxLength];
        int length=0;
        int input = 0;
        while(length<maxLength) {
            try {
                input = System.in.read();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return null;
            }
            if(input=='\n')
                break;
            bytes[length] += input;
            length++;
        }
        if(length==0)
            return null;
        return new String(bytes, 0, length);
    }
}

class N1 implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String line = Main.readLine(100);
        while(line!=null) {
            solve(line);
            line = Main.readLine(100);
        }
    }
    private void solve(String input) {
        String[] tokens = input.trim().split("\\s+");
        if(tokens.length!=2)
            return;
        int i=-1, j=-1;
        try{
            i = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
            j = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            return;
        }
        if(i<=0||j<=0)
            return;
        int low, high;
        low = (i<j) ? i :j;
        high = i+j-low;
        int max = -1;
        for(int k=i;k<=j;k++) {
            max = Math.max(max, CycleLength(k));
        }
        System.out.println(i+" "+j+" "+max);
        return;
    }
    private int CycleLength(int k) {
        int length = 1;
        long n = k;
        while(n!=1) {
            n = (n & 1)==0 ? n>>1 : n*3+1;
            length++;
        }
        return length;
    }
}
```

Above is my solution for the UVA 3n+1 question.
I have no problem working with this code on my laptop and it responds quikly.
However, the verdict is 'time limit exceeded'
What's the problem?

Comment: To get this to work in the time limits, I'm guessing you will need to [memoize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) values and their run lengths.

Answer (score 0):

Your run() method is an infinite loop that calls readLine() and readLine() does not check for end of file or end of input. So the program is trying to read another line even when the end of file or end of input is reached. So it waits forever and the time runs out.